# What is the value of the BNM angle in the figure below?

Tags: geometry

For reference:In the figure. if:
H ➔ Orthocenter of triangle ABC
and AM = MH and BN = NC; calculate the $\angle BNM$
[image]

My progress:

Below is the figure with the relationships I found

[image]

Comment: @Asher ..No...why?

Comment: EC=AC sin 25°, MD=EN=EC sin 45°, AD=AC sin 20°, BD=AD tan 45°, CN = EC cos 45°, NB=CN, ND=NB+BD, tan BNM=MD/ND

Comment: When I calculated it, the result is 25°, so maybe you can solve it without trigonometry.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu.. the result is correct...it is possible by geometry...

Comment: Shouldn't $H$ be on the other side of $AC$? It's hard to envision it being the orthocenter in the current picture.

Comment: OK. MEN ~ AEC, x=EMN=EAC.

Comment: @Vasya..Tracing the perpendicular by C with respect to AB there is only one possibility...extending the side AB. So H can only be on the top side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\small \triangle CNE\sim\triangle AME\implies \frac{CE}{AE}=\frac{EN}{ME}$$ Also, $\small EN=MD$ and $\small ME=DN$

Thus, $$\small \frac{CE}{AE}=\frac{MD}{DN}\implies\triangle AEC\sim\triangle NDM$$ Therefore, $\small x=\angle CAE=25^\circ$

Comment: This is nice observation! You can also show it by angle chasing in cyclic quadrilaterals but that is longer.